# Function name in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssrs-2012

Hi I'm migrating the SQL version ssrs reports to snowflake version in SQL
They are using isdate() function it returns o or 1 as we know , is there any fun in snowflake to work like this??

Answer (score 1):

yes , you can use `is_date()` function.

for example :

```
select * from table where is_date(column) ;
```

also read documentations here : [snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is_date-value.html)

Comment: Is_date is returns date not a Boolean value like 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

The IS_DATE function in Snowflake checks for something different than the ISDATE function in SQL Server. Specifically, it checks for whether or not a variant is a date.

```
-- These fail because the inputs are not data type variant
select is_date('2023-01-06'::date);
select is_date('2023-01-06');

-- The is_date function requires a variant type:
select is_date('2023-01-06'::date::variant);
```

You can create a UDF to get the same behavior as the SQL Server ISDATE function:

```
create or replace function ISDATE(DT string)
returns integer
language sql
as
$$
    iff(try_to_date(DT::string) is null, 0, 1)
$$;

select isdate('2023-01-06');    -- Returns 1
select isdate('2023-14-02');    -- Returns 0
select isdate('2017');          -- Returns 1
select isdate('3/4/2012')       -- Returns 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `TRY_TO_DATE` and explicit casting from BOOLEAN to INT:

```
SELECT col, 
    TRY_TO_DATE(col) AS COL_AS_DATE,
    (TRY_TO_DATE(col) IS NOT NULL)::INT AS ID_DATE_COL
FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('0'), ('2023-01-01')) sub(col);
```

Output:

[image]